# Regular expression for the language of Decimals

Tags: regex

I was told this was the answer to the task "Write down a RE for the language of Decimals" and it goes something like:

```
Decimals = (0+D(Z)*)+((0+D(Z)*).(0+D(Z)*D))

D = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9
       
Z = D+0
```

Note i am using '+' for Union

I though we could have just this > `(0+D(Z)*).(0+D(Z)*D)`

Why do we need to have `(0+D(Z)*)` before the union as well? I was thinking this would make sense if it was for any positive number, integer or decimal. Can someone let me know what is going on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In programming, we use `|` for union. `+` is a quantifier. If you want to discuss mathematical regular expressions, [cs.se] would be a better place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Decimal language they're defining, the fraction is optional. Your regular expression requires the decimal point.

The first alternative `(0+D(Z)*)` matches a number without a decimal point. The second alternative `((0+D(Z)*).(0+D(Z)*D))` matches a number with a decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

The basic numeric template regex that mirrors how a numeric function string -> number
would parse the source is as follows:

`(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`

This handles any input in any language that would convert a string to a decimal number.
This is essentially a validation.

ie.

```
 (?:
    \d+                # digits required
    (?: \. \d* )?      # optional dot digits (optional)
  |                   # or
    \. \d+             # dot and digits required
 )
```

***Modded info:***

This is an analysis of your regex *"Language of Decimals"*
showing its fallacies.

Definitions from your language :

Decimals your language formula = `(0+D(Z)*)+((0+D(Z)*).(0+D(Z)*D))`

D = `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9`

Z = `D+0`

`+` = Union

==============================

*Decimal Lang Substitutions :*

Decimals(D) =
`(0+D(D+0)*)+((0+D(D+0)*).(0+D(D+0)*D))`
Decimals(num) =
`(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0)*)+((0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0)*).(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0)*1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9))`

==============================

*Decimals to Regex Definitions :*

`+` = `|` alternation (union)

`*` = `*` quantifier (0 to many)

`.` = `\.` literal dot

`()` = `()` grouping

Regex Substitutions :

Decimals(Regex) =

`(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)*)|((0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)*)\.(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)*1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9))`

Decimals(Regex - Class factored)1 =
`([0-9]([0-9])*)|(([0-9]([0-9])*)\.([0-9]([0-9])*[1-9]))`

Decimals(Regex - Class factored)2 =
`([0-9]+)|(([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+[1-9]))`

Decimals(Regex - Class factored)3 =
`[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+[1-9])?`

***The fallacy of your "Language of Decimals" :***

```
 [0-9]+ 
 (                             # (1 start)
    \. 
    [0-9]+ 
    [1-9] 
 )?                            # (1 end)
```

OK:

- The dot group is optional

Not ok:

- The dot group requires at least 2 digits
- The dot group requires last digit not be a zero
- If the dot group present, requires digits before it

Conclusion:

This regex won't match numbers like
`87.`  ,  `.215`  , `.6`  ,  `.077`  , `44.2`  ,  `8.30`

Given that the algo - string to integer or float
requires that the above are legal, your regex is a special case used for *DISPLAY* purposes only,
and should not be used for number parsing validation (as in the case of a general numeric parser).

To label your regex *"Language of Decimals"* is erroneous in the general sense.

Comment: Your `Decimals(Regex) = (0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)*)|((0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)*)\.(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)*1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9))` factors down to this: `[0-8]|9[0-9]*|(?:[0-8]|9[0-9]*)\.(?:[0-8]|9(?:[0-9]*1)?)`